# Why does the number of backslashes increase when I add a relative path string to the set?

Tags: python, set, escaping

I encountered the following problem, when executing this code:

```py
from os import path
import re

def main():
    print('If you would like to clean some files from random noice, like "nan" types, just input 
           amount of files and correct paths to that files which you want to clean. Good luck!\n')

    amount_of_files = input("Amount of your files, please: ")
    if not amount_of_files.isdigit():
        print("Input the correct amount of files")
        return

    print('')    
    set_of_files = set()
    for i in range(int(amount_of_files)):
        file_path = input(f'Your {i+1} file path: ')
        if not path.isfile(file_path):
            print(f"The '{file_path}' is incorrect or point to the nonexistent file, check doe's all you input is correct))...\n")
            continue
        print(file_path)
        set_of_files.add(file_path)
        print(set_of_files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I enter (for example) `.\train.csv` and get this answer:

```
.\train.csv 
{'.\\\train.csv'}
```

As you can see, the number of backslashes has doubled, but when I add the exact same string as ".\train.csv" to the set without doing all the code above, the number of backslashes does not double, for example by running this code:

```
set_0 = set()
set_0.add(".\train.csv")
print(set_0)
```

I instead get:

```
{'.\train.csv'}
```

I do not understand why this happens, what it may be related to. In fact, nothing changes significantly. In the first case, we just get our path from the input string and then simply add it to the set. In the second case, we just add the same exact path to the same set, but the number of backslashes in the first case changes for some reason.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `\` is an 'escape character'. `\` followed by some selected characters gives a lot of different results. FOr example, `\n` gives a newline, `\t` gives a tab, `\a` gives a 'bell' sound. There is a whole list of these special escaped character sequences you can easily find online.

So, since `'\\train'` would actually mean `'<tab>rain'`, python automatically escapes the `'\'`. So, `'\\'` would not be an escape character but rather only a single `'\'`. You can check this(and all others) by `print('\\')`'

When you do `print(set_0)`, it prints the whole set as-is, you can look into the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods for the `set` class for knowing how.

However, when you do:

```
for i in set_0:
    print(i)
```

You get, `.       rain.csv`, which shows that `\t` is read as a `tab` when you add it directly.

Comment: But why doesn't this happen when we directly add the path '.\train.csv' to the set, we still get {'.\train.csv'} with one line in the output?  When in the first example we get two, i.e. {'.\\train.csv'}?

Comment: @konsulrima i have edited my answer to explain that as well